# jQuery Function for maximising content on timer

Tags: php, jquery, gallery, slideshow, lightbox

I'm working on a project which is going to be be as sort of showcase of images and text for a function.
I am aiming for the media to be displayed in a *grid* style on the page *(i.e. 10x5 tiles)*, and then every 5 seconds, a random tile is enlarged, shown for 5 seconds, and then minimises, using a lightbox-style effect.

As well as this, I need to be able to add photos/media as the night goes on, and it to display on the page, without disrupting the sequence of the media being showcased, (possibly by using an AJAX refresh). I have the images coming in by using a PHP script that checks the contents of a directory on the server, and then feeds it back into the gallery, (previously with Supersized). 
[documented it here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tutorial-how-to-detect-images-automatically-with-supersized ]

Does anyone know how I would go about writing this in jQuery, or if there is already a plugin that does this for me?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is break the task down into sub tasks, istead of trying to grasp it as a whole:

1. Build the html to display the images in a grid, using static images as datasource, to get it right.
2. Build the css to align the images and make sure everything fits.
3. Build a database, which will contain the imagepaths.
4. Change the datasource in the html, to use the images from a directory.
5. Start writing javascript, one thing at a time.

   1. Build a timer, that every 5 seconds jumps to the next image and either animates it up, or down, using jquery.animate()
   2. Build an ajax script, that loads new images into the image container, using jquery.ajax()

The chances are, if you break it down, and try to do something specific, that when you get stuck, you can ask something specific on here again, and you will be able to get an answer for that. Trying to do everything at once, will get you nowhere.